# Hide a specific asp.net button inside a table using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

this is my problem.

I have a table with 4 columns. (Name|Path|Date|Actions).

When i populate the table, i want to search for a string in the Path Column and if that string exist, i want to hide the Delete button in Action Column.

I dont want to hide the entire Column, just that button from that row.
If other files dont have that especific path, the button will show normally.

**ASCX Part**

```
<LayoutTemplate>
   <table id="list">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Path</th>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Actions</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
   <tr>
     <td class="fn"><%# Eval("FileName")%></td>
     <td class="fp"><%# Eval("FilePath")%></td>
     <td class="dt"><%# Eval("Date")%></td>
     <td class="del">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete"
            CssClass="lnkDeleteFile"
            CommandName="_DELETE"
            CommandArgument="<%# Eval("FileID")%>"
            runat="server" />
     </td>
   </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**JQuery Part**

I was trying to do this:

```
if($(".fp").find("specific text")){
  $(".lnkDeleteFile").hide();
}
```

But this hide all the buttons, including the ones that doesn't have that specific text. What should i do?

Comment: make the id unique so you can target that.  So something like, ID="lnkDelete-<%# Eval("FileID")%>"

Comment: @pcalkins I cant insert a Eval in the ID field. It says "The server tag is not well formed."

Comment: probably a quoting issue... using single quotes in the middle?  (sry, I'm not all that familiar with the old-school tags anymore... )